# Did the Brightblade sword possess any magical properties?

Tags: dragonlance

Sturm Brightblade's sword held the legend:

> legend says this sword will break only if I do.

Was that just the wishful thinking of a proud family, or did the sword possess magical (or clerical) properties that allowed it to live up to the legend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came across a Advanced Dungeons and Dragons module, *Knight's Sword*, set in the Dragonlance universe and it contains a background and description of the blade, including the magical properties and origin of the breaking legend.

> The *Brightblade* is a two handed sword +3 of dwarvish make. Mined from the purest ore in Thorbardin, it is remarkably resistant to rust and wear. Additional dwarven enchantments increased this resistance, making it well nigh invulnerable to the banes of the common blade. This, the edge never loses its razor sharpness, despite heavy use. In addition, the swords runes grant the wielder a +2 modifier to all reaction checks and the blade has the speed factor of a long sword. Finally, the *Brightblade* has the power to emulate a *light* spell and *protection from evil* spell once per day.

Note that it does not outright state that it will never break. The origin of the quote appears further along in the description:

> ... Only those of good heart, noble virtue and courage can wield the *Brightblade* without bringing about its destruction. Legend holds that the sword is only has strong as the heart of its user. If it is used by one of dark purpose, weak beliefs or in the service of Evil, it will shatter itself. Once this is accomplished, it may be restored only through the grace of the Gods of Good and the best weaponsmith alive. If it is ever shattered, so too will be the knighthood's honor until the blade is repaired.

Comment: I guess we'll have to try and break it and see.

Comment: @JackBNimble - Go ahead. Be aware, though, that most magical swords tend to explode when enchantments/blades are broken. :p

Comment: Do you have any canonical evidence to backup that claim?

Comment: @JackBNimble - D&D 'verse. One of the most common, possibly unwritten house rules. In theory, only the staff of the magi and staff of power are written to explode when broken. However, IIRC there was a Dragonlance article describing the effect, and implementation of same. I have also played in a tournament campaign where a +3 sword of flame exploded when broken.

Comment: The Dragon Orb didn't explode when broken. It was wicked powerful.

Comment: @JackBNimble - Sorry for the late response, I hadn't seen your comment. Magic items get saving throws when subjected to breaking stresses, and failing them can have consequences from none (it just breaks) to explosions. One of the more amusing deaths in our campaigns was a beserk fighter wielding a giant maul with a giant strength girdle, missing his target and connecting with the wizard wearing a necklace of fireballs. Needless to say, much fire, swearing, and rerolling of an entire party ensued.

Comment: @JackBNimble - Canon description found.